# Typescript conditional property failing to for function argument

Tags: typescript

The [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) should allow for smart properties but somehow everything below fails on the last line:

```
interface Props<T, S extends boolean = boolean> {
  value: T;
  isString: S;
  submit: S extends true ? (arg: string) => void : (arg: T) => void;
}

interface FalseProps<T> {
  value: T;
  isString: false;
  submit: (arg: T) => void;
}

interface TrueProps<T> {
  value: T;
  isString: true;
  submit: (arg: string) => void;
}

function fancyFunction<T>(props: Props<T>): void;
function fancyFunction<T>(props: FalseProps<T> | TrueProps<T>): void {
  if (props.isString === true) {
    props.submit('submit a string');
  } else if (props.isString === false) {
    props.submit(props.value);
  }
}

const args = {
  value: 2,
  isString: true,
  submit: (arg: string) => console.log(arg),
};

fancyFunction(args);
```

What I get is:

```
Argument of type '{ value: number; isString: boolean; submit: (arg: string) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Props<string, boolean>'.
  Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I'm using version 3.5.2

*Note*: After receiving @jcalz answer I expanded the question with a follow-up question that can be found here: [Typescript conditional property not detecting bad functional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674973/typescript-conditional-property-not-detecting-bad-functional-argument/56677740#56677740)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a bunch of issues going on here.

First of all your conditional type is being completely eagerly resolved because `fancyFunction()` is not generic in `S`, so `S` takes its default value of `boolean`, and therefore `submit` is just of type `((arg: string) => void) | ((arg: T) => void)` and `Props<T>` is no longer a conditional type at all.  That's okay, I think, but it might not behave the way you expect it to.

From the point of view of `fancyFunction`()'s call signature

```
function fancyFunction<T>(props: Props<T>): void;
```

, the `Props<T>` type is

```
interface Props<T> {
  value: T;
  isString: boolean;
  submit:  ((arg: string) => void) | ((arg: T) => void);
}
```

Your `args` value is inferred to be of type

```
const args: {
    value: number;
    isString: boolean;
    submit: (arg: string) => void;
}
```

(Aside: were you expecting that `isString` would be of type `true`?  TypeScript doesn't work that way by default.  You can use a [`const` assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions) if you want `args` to be inferred more narrowly)

And you are calling `fancyFunction(args)`.  That means that the compiler needs to infer the type `T` in `Props<T>` given `args`.  You can see in `Props<T>` that there are *two* places `T` shows up.  These are both potential *inference sites* or `T`.  Meaning, when the compiler looks at `args`, it might look at *both* the `value` property and at the  argument type of the `submit` property to try to figure out `T`.

And when it looks at the argument of the `submit` method, it sees `string`, and thus `string` becomes a candidate for `T`.  And it tries that and fails.  Blecch.

You might have been assuming that the compiler would just use `value` to infer `T`, and that the type `T` in `submit` should be a "[non-inferential type parameter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829)" (maybe you didn't think in those specific terms).  Well don't actually have those in TypeScript, but [there is an "official" way to lower the *priority* of an inference site](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731) so that it tends not to be consulted as much.  You change `T` to `T & {}` in the place where you want the inference not to happen:

```
interface Props<T> {
  value: T;
  isString: boolean;
  submit:  ((arg: string) => void) | ((arg: T & {}) => void); // change here
}
```

If I make that change, the error goes away:

```
fancyFunction(args); // okay, T inferred as number
```

Which is what you want, I think.

---

Again, you might want to pay more attention to what you're doing with the conditional type and the type of the `args` variable, just to make sure that you're doing what you intend to do.  But the `& {}` trick should at least help with your generic type inference woes.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOAeAFQBpkBlZCAD0hABMdkAjDDAGwjhGQF4mX3OAPmQBvAFDJkANzisArhABcyAgG4JyYDlJgooAObLS6yTjmMAtsDBGK1CHQa6FyAPzIAFHCiHkOXQYAlDzCUhjAtMjKXj7KBMgAZKIAvsHcoeG06sliYrQQCKzeKDByIAhgwBhc8OUAngBiZRVVIISCHliYuMro2PgEgoHKYRHqYgjV-sje+gy84pIy8krIAExEGlo6eiC+zhCbpuZWNp6zyv67+mnCkyA4bBAAdKwY+jE3m8njtQiNzUq1U+OECqiAA)

Comment: Thanks, now I get though in the function itself: `Argument of type '"submit a string"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & T & {}'.`. I also get `Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.` for the overload function. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have your code in front of me.  [I don't see those errors](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOAeAFQBpkBlZCAD0hABMdkAjDDAGwjhGQF4mX3OAPmQBvAFDJkANzisArhABcyAgG4JyYDlJgooAObLS6yTjmMAtsDBGK1CHQa6FyAPzIAFHCiHkOXQYAlDzCUhjAtMjKXj7KBMgAZKIAvsHcoeG06sliYqCQsIgoAGKyOBDo2PgEwuKSMvJKKiaa2gEgvvCs5S1mltbR3r4EaRkR2bn50PBIKlAKlbiEtRoNCnEtWjp6HcrOEL3mVjaeQ8r+O-qj0pkTYjByIAhgwBhc8E8AnsWPz68gyw8WEwuGUi2qgkCyjC43uvxeb2QHwQ33h-0BwKqylK3QqIIhyAAPnMFvjllCbhFRBpgDBPJjcAA6LbtfQ8bi8fbBOqSZAMnCMvrHDwAIiF1mQcD8rJFgRayQouM0dKB+OZbUu7N4XXK3I0kn5gqO1lVVUZawgco0ORyQA).

Comment: The first error indicates that `isSubmit()` is still being treated as a [union of functions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) and has not been narrowed.  You should use a discriminated union type like `TrueProps<T> | FalseProps<T>` instead of `Props<T>`

Comment: The second error indicates that you have put `declare` in front of one but not all of your function's overload signatures.

Comment: Trying to get a more complete example to run - the errors are now gone with the suggestions but it doesn't throw an error where I would expect it to throw - see my updated example. Tried to paste the code link previously but SO's max text limit is incl. link size in comments.

Comment: I have to go offline for a while.  It might be better for you to post a new question instead of updating an old one with subsequent problems.  I already put a fair amount of effort into my answer which addressed the question as stated, and I don't think I want to double the length of this answer anyway.