# Typescript conditional property not detecting bad functional argument

Tags: typescript

The [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) should allow for smart properties and I've managed to get help from @jcalz on the [previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671977/typescript-conditional-property-failing-to-for-function-argument) of this question. Unfortunately, while that problem was solved I still can get the type stringency that I would like. The last line below should cause an error:

```
interface Props<T, S extends boolean = boolean> {
  value: T;
  isString: S;
  submit: S extends true ? (arg: string) => void : (arg: T & {}) => void;
}

interface FalseProps<T> {
  value: T;
  isString: false;
  submit: (arg: T & {}) => void;
}

interface TrueProps<T> {
  value: T;
  isString: true;
  submit: (arg: string) => void;
}

function fancyFunction<T>(props: Props<T>): void
function fancyFunction<T>(props: TrueProps<T> | FalseProps<T>): void {
  if (props.isString === true) {
    props.submit('return a string');
  } else if (props.isString === false) {
    props.submit(props.value);
  }
}

const args1 = {
  value: 2,
  isString: true,
  submit: (arg: string) => console.log(arg),
};
fancyFunction(args1);


const args2 = {
  value: { id: 2 },
  isString: false,
  submit: (arg: { id: number }) => console.log(arg),
};
fancyFunction(args2);

const args3 = {
  value: { id: 2 },
  isString: false,
  submit: (arg: string) => console.log(arg),
};
fancyFunction(args3);
```

The typescript code can be found [here](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOAeAFQBpkBlZCAD0hABMdkAjDDAGwjhGQF4mX3OAPmQBvAFDJkANzisArhABcyAgG4JyYDlJgooAObLS6yTjmMAtsDBGK1CHQa6FyAPzIAFHCiHkOXQYAlDzCUhjAtMjKXj7KBMgAZKIAvsHcoeG06sliYqCQsIgoAGKyOBDo2PgEwuKSMvJKKiaa2gEgvvCs5S1mltbR3r7xSSKpIdKZ2bn50PBIKlAKlbiEtRoNCnEtWjp6HcrOEL3mVjaeQ8r++-ppGRHTYjByIAhgwBhc8K8AnsUvbw+IDWHiwmFwyhW1UEgWUYQiTwB70+yG+CD+SKBILBVTiSwq4OhyAAPshSt0CVU1rDJhFRBpgDBPDjcAA6XbtfQ8bi8I7BOqSZAsnCsvpnDwAcigEDAcigXDgfk5EsCLWSFApmiZoMJ7LaN25vC65X5GkkwtFp2sOqqrM2EFVGhyOTECE+-mQQxwAEYePT6rItsgAExEBn6gyHfFh0xW84xXzXIITN0gHBsCCs1gYfQJwJh5LqNEY17IkAJn2O3Kpj1e4N+gX25QiTS0ZT15Ix1p7SOosoQLtigYXWKiVvKEByCyMaDIcbpZA1jNZnN5gtFzjo-6loEV4NVmtgT0+HAAZgbG0DTRbEXbc67HJuymNA40Q-jlyVNzui-dy+zuZDPmYiFk8m4loCnwVqejpAA).

Comment: You actually don't need the `Props<T, S extends boolean = boolean>` declaration at all. The problem is the inferred type of the intermediate variables. Specifically, `isString` is inferred as `boolean` instead of `true` or `false` in all 3 cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in your other problem, `fancyFunction()` is only generic in `T` and not `S` in `Props<T, S>`.  When you only use `Props<T>`, you get a type whose `isString` property is not correlated with its `submit` property.  They are both just unions, and nothing will prevent `isString` from being `false`while `submit` is of type `(arg: string)=>void`.  So you get no errors.

Rather than try to salvage this conditional type thing with multiple type parameters, why not instead expose the implementation signature of `fancyFunction()` as its call signature?  The type `TrueProps<T> | FalseProps<T>` is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) with `isString` being the discriminant property, and it behaves as you want from both the call side and the implementation side of the function:

```
function fancyFunction<T>(props: TrueProps<T> | FalseProps<T>): void {
  if (props.isString === true) {
    props.submit('return a string');
  } else if (props.isString === false) {
    props.submit(props.value);
  }
}
```

Now at this point you will notice that all three of your calls to `fancyFunction()` give an error.  And that's because `args1`, `args2`, and `args3` are all inferred to be wider types than you intend.  A literal `true` or `false` tends to get widened to type `boolean` because that's usually what people want.  (For `let foo = true;`, most people assume a subsequent `foo = false;` should be allowed).  If you want to override that and keep the `args` variables as narrow as possible (so `true` will be inferred as type `true` and not `boolean`) then one way to do this (in TS3.4+) is with [`const` assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions):

```
const args1 = {
  value: 2,
  isString: true as const, // const assertion
  submit: (arg: string) => console.log(arg),
};
fancyFunction(args1); // okay

const args2 = {
  value: { id: 2 },
  isString: false as const, // const assertion
  submit: (arg: { id: number }) => console.log(arg),
};
fancyFunction(args2); // okay

const args3 = {
  value: { id: 2 },
  isString: false as const, // const assertion
  submit: (arg: string) => console.log(arg),
}
fancyFunction(args3); // error!
// Types of property 'submit' are incompatible
```

And that should work for you.  Hope that helps; good luck again!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#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-n5Yr9SXHJrtVWmjX2-X2dBCFAAIR0UPkGpECB0gjzI533k1ZAXQUXVsoUBo5REOAykUWU6CAA)

Comment: Probably the way to go, it is a pity though as it will confuse less proficient users as they will have to add the `as const`. The idea that I had is to add this to my [react-typeahead-ts](https://github.com/gforge/react-typeahead-ts) package so that users get a simple predictive interface. At the moment you can feed the package an object, choose that object and have it returned. Now I'm thinking that that generalization may be too costly in terms of user complexity (not my idea from the gecko - I simply converted react-typeahead to typescript - one of my earliest ts attempts). Any thoughts?

Comment: If users do `fancyFunction({value: 2, isString: true, submit: (arg: string)=>console.log(arg)})` it will work without `as const`, since the compiler will understand that the argument is expected to conform to `TrueProps<T> | FalseProps<T>` for some `T`.  It's only when you assign the object literal to some unannotated variable that you run into the problem.  The compiler doesn't know that `const args = {...}` is going to later be passed into `fancyFunction()`, so it just infers its best guess about what types people want.  The other way to do this is `const args: TrueProps<number> = ...`